# Mapping FormGroup to Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I started learn Angular and I have a simple problem. So, I want to use FormGroup and store data in the service. Problem is that receive data from FormGroup hasn't format of interface. Look at my code:

client.components.ts

```
  addClientForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('')
  });

  onSubmit(){
    console.warn(this.addClientForm.value);
    this.clientService.addClient({ this.addClientForm.value } as Client)
      .subscribe(client => {
        this.clientService.add(client);
      });
  }
```

client.components.html

```
<form [formGroup]="addClientForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <label for="first-name">Name: </label>
  <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="name">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

client.service.ts

```
  addClient(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
    return this.http.post<Client>(this.clientsURL, client, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newClient: Client) => console.log(newClient)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Client>('addedClient'))
    );

  }

  add(client: Client){
    this.clients.push(client);
  }
```

clients.ts

```
export interface Client {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to FormGroup as

```
addClientForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    id: new FormGroup('')
  });
```